# Receiving and sorting of arrays with Alamofire

Tags: json, swift, struct, alamofire

The request to help with alamofire (two days I cannot find and understand a mistake); on a task I need to obtain data of JSON through api and automatically "to spread out" them in

```
var articles = [Articles]()
```

These value (JSON) come and printed, but because of the wrong method / structure I cannot automatically spread out them.

```
let api_url = "https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?q=bitcoin&from=2019-03-13&sortBy=publishedAt&apiKey=xxx"

let formatter = "https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/"
```

And

```
struct Articles: Decodable {

    var author: String?
    var content: String?
    var description: String?
    var publishedAt: String?
    var title: String?
    var url: String?
    var urlToImage: String?

    init(dict: [String: Any]) {

        let author = dict["author"] as? String ?? ""
        // some let's...
        let urlToImage = dict["urlToImage"] as? String ?? ""

        self.author = author
        // some self's...
        self.publishedAt = publishedAt
    }

    static func getArray(from arrayOfItems: Any) -> [Articles]? {
        guard let arrayOfItems = arrayOfItems as? Array<[String: Any]> 
        else { print("ERROR at ArticleModel -> Articles"); return nil }

        return arrayOfItems.compactMap { Articles(dict: $0) }
    }
}

//Download Data

func fetchDataWithAlamofire() {

    guard let url = URL(string: api_url) else { return }

    request(url).validate().responseJSON { (dataResponse) in

        switch dataResponse.result {
        case .success(let value):
            print(value)

            if let response = Articles.getArray(from: value) {
                self.articles = response
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }

        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

Data of JSON which I obtained have to automatically (through a method) to spread out in the array and to be displayed in a simulator cell (I already made cells, a problem in Array/Dict/Struct)

Answer (score 1):

First of all why does your struct conform to `Decodable` although you don't use `JSONDecoder` at all?

You are making a common mistake, you are ignoring the root object. You need two structs and please name `Article` in singular form.

```
struct Root : Decodable {
    let status : String
    let totalResults : Int?
    let message : String? // message is used in case of an error
    let articles : [Article]?
}

struct Article : Decodable {

    let author : String?
    let content : String?
    let description : String
    let publishedAt : Date
    let title : String
    let url : URL
    let urlToImage : URL?
}
```

The initializer and the static func in `Article` is not needed.

In `fetchDataWithAlamofire()` use `responseData` rather than `responseJSON` and decode the JSON with `JSONDecoder`.
`url` and `urlToImage` can be decoded directly to `URL` and `publishedAt` can be decoded to `Date`

```
func fetchDataWithAlamofire() {

    guard let url = URL(string: api_url) else { return }

    request(url).validate().responseData { dataResponse in

        switch dataResponse.result {
        case .success(let data):
            do {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .iso8601
                let result = try decoder.decode(Root.self, from: data)
                self.articles = result.articles

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                   self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }

        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot that responded to my problem!

1) I did not remove Decodable, forgot - it is my mistake (before I made the project just through .decode ()).
2) Thanks, I thought root object it is possible to ignore and to work directly with the necessary data!

Into .decode(): As I specified, I did last HW through decode... in this project I only get acquainted with Alamofire, therefore initialization is obliged to make